# How to use expand_grid to replicate values?

Tags: r, dplyr, expand

I have the following two data frame.

First, I have the occupations data frame. Sample data frame below

```
 state <- c("00","00","32","32")
 codetype <- c("19","19","19","19")
 code <- c ("123456","123457","123456","123457")
 codetitle <- c("doctors","lawyers","doctors","lawyers")

 first <- data.frame(state,codetype,code,codetitle)
```

Second, data frame is this one

```
 state <- c("01","01","04","04","05","05")
 codetype <- c("19","19","19","19","19","19")
 code <- c("123456","123457","123456","123457","123456","123457")
 pct10 <- c(12.30,12.65,14.50,14.23,15.65,25.22)

 second <- data.frame(state,codetype,code,pct10)
```

The desired task is this..need to create new rows in the first data frame. The desired result would get the unique state values from the second data frame and create identical rows in the first.. just with new state values in the beginning. I know that I use expand_grid. My only real perplexity is how

Desired Result

```
     state       codetype       code       codetitle
      32            19          123456        Doctors 
      32            19          123457        Lawyers 
      00            19          123456        Doctors 
      00            19          123457        Lawyers 
      01            19          123456        Doctors 
      01            19          123457        Lawyers
      04            19          123456        Doctors 
      04            19          123457        Lawyers
      05            19          123456        Doctors 
      05            19          123457        Lawyers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expand.grid()` function to create the desired result:

```
state_codes <- unique(second$state)
expanded_grid <- expand.grid(state = state_codes, codetype = first$codetype[1], 
                             code = first$code, codetitle = first$codetitle)

result <- rbind(first, expanded_grid)
result

   state codetype   code codetitle
1     00       19 123456   doctors
2     00       19 123457   lawyers
3     32       19 123456   doctors
4     32       19 123457   lawyers
5     01       19 123456   doctors
6     04       19 123456   doctors
7     05       19 123456   doctors
8     01       19 123457   doctors
9     04       19 123457   doctors
10    05       19 123457   doctors
11    01       19 123456   doctors
12    04       19 123456   doctors
13    05       19 123456   doctors
14    01       19 123457   doctors
15    04       19 123457   doctors
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```r
library(dplyr)
second %>%
  select(-pct10) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  left_join(distinct(first, code, codetitle), by = "code") %>%
  bind_rows(first)
#    state codetype   code codetitle
# 1     01       19 123456   doctors
# 2     01       19 123457   lawyers
# 3     04       19 123456   doctors
# 4     04       19 123457   lawyers
# 5     05       19 123456   doctors
# 6     05       19 123457   lawyers
# 7     00       19 123456   doctors
# 8     00       19 123457   lawyers
# 9     32       19 123456   doctors
# 10    32       19 123457   lawyers
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you may use the `plyr::rbind.fill` along with `left join`

```r
third <-  plyr::rbind.fill(first,second) %>% select(-codetitle,-pct10) %>% 
left_join(first %>% select(code, codetitle) %>% unique(), by=c('code'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   state codetype   code codetitle
1     00       19 123456   doctors
2     00       19 123457   lawyers
3     32       19 123456   doctors
4     32       19 123457   lawyers
5     01       19 123456   doctors
6     01       19 123457   lawyers
7     04       19 123456   doctors
8     04       19 123457   lawyers
9     05       19 123456   doctors
10    05       19 123457   lawyers
```